# PeriodicTimer running inside a Task

Tags: c#, timer, task, .net-6.0, periodictimer

I have a top-level class that is a long-running management class for various requirements for my application.

I need to have some kind of Timer set-up which will monitor any errors around my application, pausing a Quartz Scheduler execution for x minutes and then perform certain actions on the back of it.

Once the Class is fully configured, I call the below Method:

```
private async Task BeginActionMonitoring()
{
      var _actionMonitoringTimer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
      while (await _actionMonitoringTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
      {
          await ExecuteErrorCheckActions();
      }
}
```

The problem I have is that I don't want to have the whole class dormant and stuck within a While-Loop.

Is there a best-practice of how to handle this and have it running parallel with the Class?

Is the below the correct way to do this?

```
private async Task BeginActionMonitoring()
{
      var _actionMonitoringTimer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

      Task.Run(() => {
             while (await _actionMonitoringTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
             {
                 await ExecuteErrorCheckActions();
             }
      });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *"The problem I have is that I don't want to have the whole class dormant and stuck within a While-Loop."* -- Why? Could you edit the question and explain what's the problem in more details? What's the actual observable undesirable effect that you want to prevent?

Comment: There is no such concept of a class running. Your first snippet is fine.

Comment: Even ignoring how much of a code smell the second snippet is, it's also broken -- you never await anything in it despite declaring it as `async`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a timer for this purpose, without a `Task`, but you can of course run it inside a task too.

```cs
var _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Then use it like so:

```cs
_timer.Elapsed += (_, _) => DoSomeChecks();
_timer.Enabled = true;
```

you can disable it if need be by setting the `Enabled` property to false.